# How to parse JSON string in Thymeleaf for spring-boot application without using Object Mapper?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to parse following JSON to display information in table format on the web page as shown in the image below. I have achieved this by converting JSON string to object using ObjectMapper and then adding it to model for web page. I am wondering if there any way to directly parse JSON string to Thymeleaf without using Object Mapper?

JSON String

```
{
    "kernelVersion": "4.4.0",
    "videoAppVersion": "1.2.3",
    "zigbeeAppVersion": "1.2",
    "overrideFiles": [{
        "path": "/0/21/gateway.conf",
        "sizeBytes": 0
    }, {
        "path": "/1/21/gateway2.conf",
        "sizeBytes": 2
    }, {
        "path": "/2/21/gateway2.conf",
        "sizeBytes": 2
    }],
    "sshKeyVersion": "ZA-1515092259"
}
```

Desired output
[image]

HTML code for table diaply

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Camera Name</label></td>
        <td th:text="${cameraDetails.cameraInfo.cameraName}">10.103.3.120</td>
    </tr>
    .......
    <tr>
        <td><label>Override files</label></td>
        <td>
            <table style="width:100%; margin-left: 0px;">
            <tr>
            <td> <label>File Path</label></td>
            <td><label> File Size</label></td>
            </tr>
                <tr th:each="overrideFile  : ${cameraDetails.cameraInfo.overrideFiles}">
                    <td th:text="${overrideFile.path}">001</td>
                    <td th:text="${overrideFile.sizeBytes}">001</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I gues you should use some Javascript tool to do what you want to do. Otherwise in the controller that will render the HTML fragment you can deserializa the json into java Object and then pass the Java object to the `org.springframework.ui.Model` and handle the model in the thymeleaf fragment